# Does the following condition implies full outer measure?

Tags: measure-theory, set-theory, axiom-of-choice

Let $X \subseteq 2^{\omega}$ be a set of positive Lebesgue measure. Suppose that for every $\eta, \nu \in 2^{<\omega}$ of the same length, the measure of $X$ above $\eta$ is the same as the measure of $X$ above $\nu$.
Is it necessarily true that the outer measure of $X$ is $1$?
If the answer is positive, do we need countable choice for the proof?

Answer (score 4):

Yes. Suppose not, look at $X^c$ which is of positive measure. By Lebesgue Density Theorem, there exists $\sigma, \tau\in 2^{\omega}$ (WLOG might assume they have the same length) such that $X$ and $X^c$ has measure $>\frac{1}{2}$ above $\tau, \sigma$ respectively. By hypothesis, $X$ has measure $>\frac{1}{2}$ above $\sigma$ too. But then above $\sigma$, $X$ intersects with $X^c$ which is absurd. I don't think AC is required in the proof of Lebesgue density theorem (at least in the setting of Cantor space).

Comment: The last sentence is not quite true, see my answer.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Well I feel if the failure of countable AC is causing the problem to be not well formulated, then it seems like another story different from the question "is countable choice needed for the proof". I would like to think about the question as formulated in whatever universe such that the objects mentioned actually make sense (of course countable AC can fail but it might just fail somewhere above some big cardinals....)

Comment: You could argue, like that, that no choice is needed for any result at all if the result is limited to sets of bounded rank. But that's false. I am not claiming that countable choice is equivalent to the Lebesgue measure being well defined, but without something which looks like countable choice (at least for sets of reals) you can't *ensure* that the problem is well defined.

Comment: @JingZhang can you sketch (or give a reference for) a proof of Lebesgue density for the Cantor space that doesn't make use of countable choice?

Comment: No that not what I argued. I mean there is difference between statement is made false and a statement is made non-sensical. But I agree this is subtle and maybe subject to different people's taste. In wacky universes you can always try to make sense of things (in an ad hoc way) that don't seem to make sense any more anyways...

Comment: @Lebmes: I need to get some sleep now. So if you are curious (I'm pretty sure there are lots of sources) but I vaguely remember maybe you could find something in Algorithmic Randomness and Complexity (Rod Downey, D. Hirschfeldt, Springer, 2010) first chapter i guess.

Comment: @JingZhang I'm looking at the proof of theorem 4.2.3 in the book that you mentioned, and it seems that they make use of sigma-additivity (hence countable choice) in the proof of fact (ii). Am I missing something?

Comment: If you want to be more concrete, you have used countable choice to prove there are even sets of positive measure to begin with.

Comment: @Lebmes: Well in that sense yes. But when you talk about measure on a sigma algebra, you always require sigma additivity. So in this case, if that is assumed then you don't need any more instance of countable choice.

Answer (score 1):

The measure theoretic part was answered, so let me complement it by answering the choice related question. The axiom of countable choice is needed on a far more fundamental level when you talk about measure theory.

It is consistent that the real numbers are a countable union of countable sets. In that case there is no $\sigma$-additive Borel measure (except the $0$ measure), not even on the Borel sets.

But countable choice ensures that countable unions of countable sets are countable, and that we're fine. Of course, you could still do measure theory in the absence of any choice by working with sets that have Borel codes (really countable choice ensures that every Borel set has a code), but this is just terrible for your health. You can look in Fremlin's "Measure Theory" (vol. 5) for more information on measure theory without choice.

Comment: Consider the outer measure-version of Lebesgue's density theorem for the Cantor space. Countable choice is not required for the formulation of the theorem, but is it still required for the proof? I guess that this is really the part that interests me right now.

Comment: If every open interval has measure $0$, what use is the outer measure?

Comment: Other than the user who posted this answer, is there anything actually wrong with it?